# stateful jupyter notebook in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook

Trying to deploy a stateful jupyter notebook in Kubernetes, but not able to save the code written in a notebook, whenever the notebook pod is going down all the code is being deleted. I tried to use persistent volume but unable to achieve the expected result.

UPDATE

Changed mount path to "/home/jovyan" as jyputer saves the ipynb in this location. But now getting PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jovyan/.local' while deploying the pod.

````
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jupyter-ingress
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: jupyter-notebook-service
    servicePort: 8888

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jupyter-notebook-service
spec:  
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: jupyter-notebook
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP    
    port: 8888
    targetPort: 8888

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: jupyter-notebook
  labels:
    app: jupyter-notebook
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: "jupyter-notebook-service"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jupyter-notebook
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jupyter-notebook
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: dsx-spark
      volumes:
        - name: jupyter-pv-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: jupyter-pv-claim 
      containers:
      - name: minimal-notebook
        image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
        command: ["start-notebook.sh"]
        args: ["--NotebookApp.token=''"]
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/home/jovyan"
            name: jupyter-pv-storage

---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jupyter-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: jupyter-pv-storage
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce 
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

---
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jupyter-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: jupyter-pv-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce 
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/jovyan"

---

apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: jupyternotebook-pv-storage
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  labels:
provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
parameters:
    diskformat: zeroedthick
    ```
````

Comment: Any reason you aren’t using Hub instead?

Comment: mostly focusing on writing spark code in the notebook that's why using an image:jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest

Comment: @NitinAshok I can't see `volumeClaimTemplates` in your StatefulSet. Could you please elaborate more on what have you tried in terms of persistent volumes? Also, please see this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-storage) and tell me if you have done that.

Comment: @OhHiMark I have made some changes to mount path but now getting permission denied error while deploying the pod I update the code. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: @NitinAshok You need to set permissions for that folder to 777 so the container running as a particular user would be able to write on that.

Comment: Hello,

I just open-sourced a tool to manage Jupyter notebooks on Kubernetes without JupterHub and its burden, notebook-on-kube relies on existing tools/features of the Kubernetes ecosystem (Helm, RBAC, ingress-nginx, HPA, Prometheus metrics), learn more about it at https://github.com/machine424/notebook-on-kube, give it a try and let me know :)

Answer (score 3):

The Pod with jupyter notebook is non-root user so unable to mount the so we are
using initContainers to change user/permission of the Persistent Volume Claim before creating the Pod.

````
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: jupyter-notebook
  labels:
    app: jupyter-notebook
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: "jupyter-notebook-service"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jupyter-notebook
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jupyter-notebook
    spec:

      serviceAccountName: dsx-spark
      volumes:
        - name: ci-jupyter-storage-def
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: my-jupyter-pv-claim 
      containers:
      - name: minimal-notebook
        image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8888
        command: ["start-notebook.sh"]
        args: ["--NotebookApp.token=''"]
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/home/jovyan/work"
            name: ci-jupyter-storage-def

      initContainers:
      - name: jupyter-data-permission-fix
        image: busybox
        command: ["/bin/chmod","-R","777", "/data"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: ci-jupyter-storage-def
          mountPath: /data```
````

Comment: I am getting 302 response when i hit the service

[I 11:24:35.924 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 11:24:35.925 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /opt/conda/share/jupyter/lab
[I 11:24:35.927 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan
[I 11:24:35.927 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.4 is running at:
http://jupyter-notebook-7499c4447b-knblc:8888/
Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
 302 GET / (10.244.1.149) 0.83ms

Answer (score 0):

As I have already mentioned in the comments you need to make sure that:

1. The storage for a given Pod must either be provisioned by a PersistentVolume Provisioner based on the requested storage class, or pre-provisioned by an admin. The `volumeClaimTemplates` will provide [stable storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-storage) using PersistentVolumes. PersistentVolumes associated with the Pods’ PersistentVolume Claims are not deleted when the Pods, or StatefulSet are deleted.
2. The container is running as a user that has the permissions to access that volume. It can be done by changing the permissions to 777 or as you already noticed by using a proper initContainers.